# Can I parent objects to parts of a group instance?

Tags: groups

Let's say I have a group of ten parts and I want to parent an object to one of the objects in a group instance. Is that possible?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

No, an instance is just an [empty object](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Empties) (with a [DupliGroup](http://wiki.blender.org/index.php/Doc:2.6/Manual/Modeling/Objects/Duplication/DupliGroup)).

You should place an empty where the target object is located within the group. Parent the empty to the group instance and then parent your object to the empty.